# How to create images with English alphabets (A-Z, a-z, 0-9) in Python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, deep-learning, dataset

I want to prepare a dataset for the recognition of English Alphanumeric characters. I want to train my Deep learning model to recognize the characters. Image size should be 32 * 32 or 28 * 28. And Characters should be scaled with the height and width of the Image. Given below is the expected Output.

[Character "A" scaled with the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqDpU.png)

I have tried getsize() but I am not able to scale character with the image size.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import os,glob
import numpy as np
import random

parentPath=r"CaptchaDataset\\"


charactersList=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
fontTypes=[]

for font in glob.glob("fonts\\*"): # Create Image for every font
    fontTypes.append(os.path.abspath(font))
    
for index,character in enumerate(charactersList):
    
    path=os.path.join(parentPath,character+"_"+str(index))
    os.mkdir(path)
    
    
    for imageCounter in range(len(fontTypes)):
        for repeats in range(3): #Number of Images
            img = Image.new('1', (28, 28), color = 'black')
            fnt = ImageFont.truetype(fontTypes[imageCounter], random.randint(30,50))
            w,h=fnt.getsize(character)
            d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
            d.text(((28-w)/2-5,((28-h)/2)-5), character, font=fnt, fill=(255),align="center") #TO ALIGN CHARACTER IN CENTER
            img=np.pad(img,pad_width=10, mode='constant', constant_values=0) #Manually added padding
            img=Image.fromarray(img)
            img.save(path+"\\"+str(imageCounter)+"_"+str(repeats)+".jpg")
```

[UnExpected Output of Above program. "g" is cropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeT78.jpg)

Comment: I would draw the character in a larger image, then crop it to your desired size.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple: Create the image after creating the font.

Instead of creating 28x28 pixels image, and drawing a character that may be larger than the image, create the font, get the size, and create the image according to the font's size.

- Create the font, and get the font's size:

  ```
   fnt = ImageFont.truetype(fontTypes[imageCounter], random.randint(30, 50))
   w, h = fnt.getsize(character)
  ```
- Set image size according to font size and create the image:

  ```
   img_w, img_h = w + 20, h + 20  # Add 20 pixels padding (assume 10 pixels from each side).
   img = Image.new('L', (img_w, img_h), color='black')  # Replace '1' with 'L' (8-bit pixels, black and white - we fill 255 so we can't use 1 bit per pixel)
  ```
- Draw the character at the center of the image:

  ```
   d.text(((img_w-w)/2, (img_h-h)/2), character, font=fnt, fill=255, align="center") # TO ALIGN CHARACTER IN CENTER
  ```

---

Here is a complete (updated) code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import os,glob
import numpy as np
import random

parentPath = "CaptchaDataset\\"

charactersList=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
fontTypes=[]

for font in glob.glob("fonts\\*"): # Create Image for every font
    fontTypes.append(os.path.abspath(font))
    
for index,character in enumerate(charactersList):    
    path = os.path.join(parentPath,character + "_" + str(index))

    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)
     
    for imageCounter in range(len(fontTypes)):
        for repeats in range(3): # Number of Images
            #img = Image.new('1', (28, 28), color = 'black')
            fnt = ImageFont.truetype(fontTypes[imageCounter], random.randint(30, 50))
            w, h = fnt.getsize(character)
            img_w, img_h = w + 20, h + 20  # Add 20 pixels padding (assume 10 pixels from each side).
            img = Image.new('L', (img_w, img_h), color='black')  # Replace '1' with 'L' (8-bit pixels, black and white - we fill 255 so we can't use 1 bit per pixel)
            d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
            d.text(((img_w-w)/2, (img_h-h)/2), character, font=fnt, fill=255, align="center") # TO ALIGN CHARACTER IN CENTER
            #img = np.pad(img, pad_width=10, mode='constant', constant_values=0) #Manually added padding
            #img = Image.fromarray(img)
            img.save(path + "\\" + str(imageCounter) + "_" + str(repeats) + ".jpg")
```

---

Few sample results:
[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]